# Voice control of Tello drone with Scratch

Tags: voice-recognition, mit-scratch, tello-drone

I am a teacher and I have a Tello drone which I can control using MIT Scratch 3, an offline version of Scratch the comes with a Tello extension. I can also control a sprite using voice commands with an online version of Scratch available at [machinelearningforkids](https://scratch.machinelearningforkids.co.uk/).  I want my students to be able to write a Scratch program to control a Tello drone with voice commands.  How can I put the two together please?  I realise I could achieve this with Python, but I would like to do this with the simplicity of the Scratch interface.